# adding a double to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

im trying to add a double value that represents the stamina of my player into a jTextArea after i click my north button cant seem to do it heres my code:

```
private void northButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
    game.playerMove(MoveDirection.NORTH);
    update();
    double playerStamina = player.getStaminaLevel();

    //tried this
    String staminaLevel = Double.toString(playerStamina);
    jTextArea1.setText("Stamina: " + staminaLevel);
}
```

im new here sorry if this is not right

heres the main method

```
public class Main 
{
/**
 * Main method of Lemur Island.
 * 
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // create the game object
    final Game game = new Game();
    // create the GUI for the game
    final LemurIslandUI  gui  = new LemurIslandUI(game);
    // make the GUI visible
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

and heres the class

```
public class LemurIslandUI extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
private Game game;
private Player player;
/** 
 * Creates a new JFrame for Lemur Island.
 * 
 * @param game the game object to display in this frame
 */
public LemurIslandUI(final Game game) 
{
    this.game = game;     
    initComponents();
    createGridSquarePanels();
    update();      
}

private void createGridSquarePanels() {

    int rows = game.getIsland().getNumRows();
    int columns = game.getIsland().getNumColumns();
    LemurIsland.removeAll();
    LemurIsland.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            GridSquarePanel panel = new GridSquarePanel(game, row, col);
            LemurIsland.add(panel);
        }
    }  
}

/**
 * Updates the state of the UI based on the state of the game.
 */
private void update()
{ 
    for(Component component : LemurIsland.getComponents()) 
    {
        GridSquarePanel gsp = (GridSquarePanel) component;
        gsp.update();
}
    game.drawIsland();

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the stamina value in the JTextArea?

Comment: So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Have you implemented action listener in your class?

Comment: yup thats right user2777005

Comment: wont show up when i click north button

Comment: @craigsmith do you mind showing your class and main please.

Comment: Poor mans debugger: Try putting a System.out.println("Here"); statement in the above code and click the button, if it doesn't print the code is never reaching this point and so the listener is flawed, this should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Obvious .. but did you set the rows/columns for JTextArea ? Is the JTextArea being displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class doesn't seem to be implmeneting `ActionListener`, therefore the action on your button will not be triggered.

Your class declaration should be:

```
public class LemurIslandUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
```

And put the code for your button action inside:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
```

Alternatively, you can use an `anonymous class` to implement the code for your button, instead of making your class implement the `ActionListener`. Something like:

```
final JButton button = new JButton();

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent)
        {
            //code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`jTextArea1.setText("Stamina: " + player.getStaminaLevel());`

Using anything + string does auto casting to string.

Comment: Sorry i missed the button part, your reply about the action listener is really what he need.